# What does the leakage current graph of the LM13700 OTA stand for?

Tags: current, temperature

On the datasheet ( http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm13700.pdf ) there is a figure of leakage current- temperature. Is this the output leakage current?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you include the figure in your question to save people having to look it up? That way you might attract good answers. In any case, that's a 37 page datasheet and you didn't even give the page or figure number.

Comment: you're right, I forgot to reference the figure. It's figure 6 on page 6

Comment: Take a screenshot and add it in.

Answer (score 0):

This is the worst case CM input & output current at Vo=Vin=36V at abs. max Vcc due to input diodes vs Temp. and output emitter follower unbiased.